# VBA Selenium Sendkeys Modifier Keys

Tags: vba, selenium, sendkeys

I'm trying to use Sendkeys for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> but

```
.Sendkeys ("^+B")
```

is not working.

Comment: I don't know what reference might be required for VBA - I use Java with my Selenium, but in my case, I use something like `.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROl+Keys.SHIFT+"B")`

Comment: Are you trying to show the bookmarks bar?

Comment: no I'm using it to add bcc while composing mail.

Comment: this is one of the example I need to send these type of key combo multiple times

Comment: still not able to use Sendkeys for Ctrl+Shift+B

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a Keys object:

```
Dim keyObj As Selenium.Keys
Set keyObj = New Selenium.Keys
bot.SendKeys keyObj.Control & keyObj.Shift & "B"
```

Comment: Not Working for me

Comment: What isn't working? It isn't creating the object? It isn't pressing the keys? Be specific.

Comment: Not Creating Object

Comment: Runtime Error '404'
Object Required